# Get Result of ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript alert

Tags: javascript, asp.net, scriptmanager

i need to show a javascript alert on a button click and after user click ok on alert box i need to redirect to another page.i'm using following code

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "ss", "<script>alert('Report Data Not Found ! ')</script>",false);
            Response.Redirect(ResolveUrl("~/Reports/Transmittal/OverDueTransmittal/TransmittalReports_Form.aspx"));
```

currently alert is not shown but it redirects to the next page.if i remove the "Response.Redirect" part it shows the alert.how can i make both these to work at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "ss", "<script>alert('Report Data Not Found ! '); location.href = "/Reports/Transmittal/OverDueTransmittal/TransmittalReports_Form.aspx</script>", false);
```

You might need to tweak the URL a bit. Response.Redirect is a server-side redirect. You need a client-side one, initiated from JavaScript. Setting location.href will do it from JavaScript.

Comment: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "ss", "<script>alert('Report Data Not Found ! '); location.href = '" + ResolveUrl("~/Reports/SqaudCheck/OverDueSqaudCheck/Squad Check_Reports_Form.aspx") + "'</script>", false);

Answer (score 0):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "message", "alert('**Put whatever message you want to display here.**');
location.href='**www.segroch.com**';",true); 

~ segroch.com = Page to redirect to.
```

This should work fine.